# Delete App DB present in mobile from the App using cordova

Tags: android, ios, database, cordova

I want to drop the complete database related to my app from the app on occurence of some particular event.

How can I accomplish this ? I am using cordova to build my app and my app is for both Android and iOS platforms.

Comment: where is the database store?

Comment: in the filesystem of mobile

Comment: Ok. Since its just a file-  fileentry.remove(success, fail); should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function removefile(){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("/data/data/YourPackage/databases/YouDbName.db", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotRemoveFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotRemoveFileEntry(fileEntry){
    console.log(fileEntry);
    fileEntry.remove(success, fail);
}

function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}
```